# How can I produce a continuous sound of pressure 70 dB with randomized noise?

Tags: noise, sound, component-selection

How can I achieve a sound system that can produce a continuous sound with randomized noise in the range 70-75 dB?

I need that for conducting a medical experiment in which the doctor measures stress hormones levels induced due to prolonged exposure to moderate sound level.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132280/discussion-on-question-by-power-how-can-i-produce-a-continuous-sound-of-pressure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating white noise is easy - there are white noise machines that you can buy.  You can also easily generate white noise using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or other audio editor programs.  You could also use [Puredata](https://puredata.info/) or [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/) to generate white noise.

None of those options can guarantee the output level of the sound.

You will have to measure that.

You will need a calibrated sound pressure level meter.  You can buy or rent such a meter.  They aren't terribly expensive.

Set your white noise source running, then measure the sound level where your subject is sitting.  Adjust the volume of the noise source to get the required 70dBA.

---

It doesn't matter really how loud the source is as long as it is louder than what you need.

The sound level drops the further you are from the source.

You really have no choice but to measure the sound level.

Comment: Thanks JRE that was a conclusive answer.